# C++ functions as parameters Binary Search

Tags: c++

I am new to stack overflow and I couldn't find an appropriate answer in the questions already asked.

What I am trying to do is pass a function as a parameter to another function (binary search tree, inorder traversal).

```
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::createList(orderedLinkedList<elemType>& listIn)
{
    this->inorderTraversal(listIn.insert);
}
```

What this is supposed to do is do an inorder traversal of the binary tree and insert each element into an orderedLinkedList. I just can't seem to get it to work when passing ListIn.insert().

I can get the inorder to work with other functions passed to it. This function works when passed to inorder like this :  inOrderTraversal(update)

```
template <class elemType>
void update(elemType& x)
{
    x = 2 * x;
};
```

Here is the definition of the inorder traversal:

```
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorder(binNodeType<elemType>* p, void(*visit) (elemType& item)) const
{
    if (p != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(p->lLink, *visit);
        (*visit)(p->info);
        inorder(p->rLink, *visit);
    }
}
```

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean, you can't get it to work? Are you getting compile errors? Is the program failing to link? Producing bad output?

Comment: It just won't compile. I think  jakub_d really shed some insight as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` method is not actually a single-argument c function, c++ methods have a hidden first argument that is passed as the value for `this`, which in this case should be the value of `listIn`.

The c++ method of implementing this scenario would be using something like std::function for the visit callback, see some examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function .
Instead of a function pointer you would be passing an object that has an `()` operator. The object can contain as much internal state as it needs.

The traditional c-like approach would be callback-with-extra-state, `visit` would be a two-argument function like `visit(void * cbData, elemType& item)` and inorder would take an extra `void * cbData` argument that it would not touch and just pass it along to `visit` calls. (the called function can then e.g. cast cbData to list and invoke its insert method...)

Comment: Pedantic note: The hidden `this` parameter is the easiest and most common way of implementing `this`, but even if something different is used, the result is the same: class member functions (AKA methods) are not compatible with free functions.